# AWS S3 Restoring Object Issue using AWS .NET sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have configured life cycle to restore archived object from glacier to S3 using s3 console which is working fine.

Now I am trying to restore archive object from glacier to S3 programmatically  using .NET sdk. I am able to perform operation like PUT, GET, DELETE file from S3, but not able to restore archive object from glacier to S3.

Below are the implementation information (e.g. Request Parameter) and exception information:

- Request Parameters

  [image]
- Exception occurred While Restoring Object -

  [image]
- Exception Details

  [image]

**Exception:**
"The XML you provided was not in well-formed or did not validate against our published schema".

Comment: have you tried the code in example of AWS Documentation  : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/restore-object-dotnet.html

Comment: @KushVyas: We are following this article to implement the functionality..